# Data about bathymetry for Europe

Tags: data-request

I am looking for bathymetry data for European seas, and in particular for the Mediterranean see. Those datasets seem to exist (I could find some maps of bathymetry) but I would like to have the raw information (depth) and not the coloured maps. Raster or vector formats are OK, but I prefer raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Raster or vector formats are OK, but I prefer raster.

Are you looking for maps with isolines ("isobathes")? Probably some formats available for download on the [EMODnet Portal](http://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu/geographic-grid?menu=19) will be suitable for you (using appropriate software).

> I would like to have the raw information (depth)

You could also download an XYZ file.

```
$ more -10 C2.xyz
3.50104167;69.99895833;-3227.40;
3.50312500;69.99895833;-3226.40;
3.50520833;69.99895833;-3233.00;
3.50729167;69.99895833;-3225.60;
3.50937500;69.99895833;-3228.40;
3.51145833;69.99895833;-3232.20;
3.51354167;69.99895833;-3234.00;
3.51562500;69.99895833;-3238.80;
3.51770833;69.99895833;-3230.80;
3.51979167;69.99895833;-3228.80;
--More--(0%)
```

[image: how to download maps]

Answer (score 2):

The Global roughly 1km topography and bathymetry data here

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/

includes the Mediterranean Sea region. The website has tools for
download regions as well as the entire global set. The data is available
for download as a large single file (for the globe). The site also has
links to interactive pages that can be used to select sub-regions for
download.